# WebpiCmdLine.exe NetFramework4 Access Denied

Tags: .net, powershell, access-denied, web-platform-installer

I've recently started learning Powershell and it's become a very important tool in my toolbelt.

I am currently attempting to configure a number of remote environments with powershell and have been quite successful thus far. However, I am running into an issue while attempting to install the .NET 4 Framework using the WebPICmdLine.exe tool.

```
Invoke-Command {Invoke-Expression U:\WebPICmdLine.exe /Products: NetFramework4 /AcceptEULA} -Session $RemoteSessionWithAdminAccountCredentials
```

The tool begins installing instantly but fails out while installing .NET 4. It comes up "Access Denied" while attempting to run the DotNetFramework4.msu /quiet statement. The Credentials are for a System Administrator Account, and the file is getting extracted to the AppData Folder for that particular user. I'm not sure why this would come up access denied.

Has anyone ran into a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

WebPICmdLine as well as Web PI do require administrators privileges. From the [system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) of Web PI: "You must have administrator privileges on your computer to run the Web Platform Installer."

Sometimes there also might be problems with the installer itself and not with `WebPICmdLine`. You can also try to install the framework by invoking the installer directly from the folder `%localappdata%\microsoft\web platform installer\installers` where it is cached by Web PI. This way, you can get more details on the error.

Answer (score 0):

This action may require elevated privileges on vista, win7 and 2008, not just admin account. Try using Local System instead of interactive user account.

Comment: I am able to install with same user credentials when executing WebPICmdLine.exe on the local machine. I'll attempt this to see if it will resolve the issue.